# how to use where in inner join in pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, where-clause

```
SELECT
  demo_user.email_id,
  demo_user.role,
  demo_user.information,
  demo_user.role,
  demo_user.name,
  demo_user_search.ref_user,
  demo_user_search.ip,
  demo_user_search.search_content,
  demo_user_search.search_timestamp
FROM demo_user
  INNER JOIN demo_user_search
  ON demo_user.id=demo_user_search.ref_user
WHERE demo_user.role=3
```

I had no trouble till "demo_user.id=demo_user_search.ref_user" but I'm not able to get data using WHERE clause.
Please Help

Comment: There is no table called user... that must be why the `where` is not working

Comment: changed that but still the same
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"

Comment: Edit question with sample data and error output

Comment: are your user you have demo_user.role = 3 .? which datatype is demo_user.role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 du.role,
 du.name,
 du.email_id,
 du.information,
 du.contact_no,
 dus.ref_user,
 dus.ip,
 dus.search_content,
 dus.search_timestamp 
FROM 
 demo_user du 
INNER JOIN
 demo_user_search dus 
ON du.id=dus.ref_user WHERE du.role='3'
```

Got the query right thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You have use "user.role=3" and there is 2 tables **demo_user** and **demo_user_search**. please recheck the table name.